# MultiAutoCompleteTextView like Text messaging Application with custom users list

Tags: android

I try to make my own MultiAutoCompleteTextView to make it works like the recipient field in the text messaging application in Android but with my own users list.

I used custom library on Github but no one seems to correspond to my need.

I see there's something like this here https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ, but I didn't manage to provide my own users list instead of phone contacts list or phone mails list (What a pity because this is absolutly what I need)

Did someone succeed to make this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [TokenAutoComplete library](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)  for that. It is easy to implement and use.

Comment: I'm gonna try this library, I already saw it on Github but I thought that I couldn't supply my own user lists. Is the dropdown suggestion list and chips are customizable ? (like add picture of the user)

Comment: Absolutely great ! This is exactly what I need ;)
Thanks for the help !
A last thing, do you know how to manage the onclick on a token ? I succeded to change the background via drawable/backgrounds, but I want to programmatically change the text color and the picture that I added

Comment: Just have to create my own view class, and inflate my custom layout to match this new class